# PubSub Unacked messages are not Showing up when using dataflow as subscriber

Tags: apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, google-dataflow

I have a dataflow pipeline which reads messages from a subscription. It is working fine when messages are coming in correct format. But when messages are not in proper format ,it's throwing error. I decided to use the dead letter topic when there is some bad message it will be pushed to the topic as I can't change the code immediately. I updated the subscription with a dead letter topic and provided necessary permissions. I can see the unack message count increasing in subscription
but it's never reaching to dead letter queue.

Questions:

```
  > Why the dead letter functionality is not working,Am I missing anything.

  >I can see unack message count in subscription but why I can't see them when I use gcloud pull message.
```

Comment: Are you sure you are following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#forwarding_to)? If yes can you add to the question some example code how do you add `dead-letter topic` to subscription and example of `gcloud` command you are using?

Comment: Hi @vitooh as per  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67206517/nack-not-send-back-to-google-cloud-pub-sub-from-dataflow-when-there-is-an-error],the feature is not yet supported in Dataflow.